# Mule ESB - overriding Media-Type of HTTP Request

Tags: rest, api, http, mule, esb

I'm trying to send SOAP envelope with standard mule HTTP Request and I'm having trouble with setting Media-Type of an outbound request. The webservice expects "application/soap+xml", but setting 'Content-Type: application/soap+xml' header in POST Request or setting mime-type to payload doesn't seem to work. I keep getting error 415 - unsupported media type. Does anybody have any idea what can I do to resolve this issue? My XML code so far (I've changed names and addresses, the idea stays the same):

```
     <flow name="get-report">
    <http:listener config-ref="asdf-httpListenerConfig" path="/" doc:name="HTTP"/>

    <custom-transformer encoding="UTF-8" mimeType="application/soap+xml" class="Authorization" doc:name="Java"/>
    <logger message="#[payload]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>

    <http:request config-ref="HTTP_Request_Configuration" path="path.svc" method="POST" doc:name="HTTP">
        <http:request-builder>
            <http:header headerName="Content-Type" value="application/soap+xml"/>
            <http:header headerName="action" value="someAction"/>
            <http:header headerName="host" value="someHost"/>
        </http:request-builder>
    </http:request>
    <logger message="#[payload]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
</flow>
```

The 'Authorization' transformer isn't really relevant, right now I just hardcode entire envelope and return it.
Also, POST'ing an envelope via soapUI with the same addresses, content type and media-type works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Setting the header in the http:request should definitely set the Content-Type header, so i would suggest this is not the issue. Though it is dependant on the API implementation, 415 Unsupported Media Type can be caused by the requests [Content-Type, Content-Encoding or by inspecting the data directly](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.5.13). Perhaps it could be caused by the XML structure.